# Baseband circuit is not working as expected

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, differential-amplifier, band-pass

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSAniT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit when printed on PCB, output isn't a bandpass signal as expected. When I am checking the output with CRO across output pin and 0V, attenuated signal is observed while in simulation there was 30-40dB gain. I could not simulate in the Circuit Lab. Please be kind for my shortcomings. I used ADS and Multisim. The op amp LM358 is biased from 0-5V.
I am stuck with this circuit for a long time. I need help.
The main problem: centre frequency shifted from 4KHz to 5KHz and the maximum gain at centre frequency is only 15dB while in simulation it is 35dB. Please help me troubleshoot this one or, suggest an alternative to use easily to convert differential signal to single-ended, bandpass amplified signal.

Comment: That's a lot of circuit to digest at once! So, as everyone else, I'd first check the power supply of my opamps. Once I'm confident my supplies are sufficient, I'd go and probe every sensible point of my schematic. Is your virtual ground as expected? (I have doubts about your system's behaviour when there's no AC on the input!) Is the signal after C1 / C4 as expected? After C5/C6? After R6/R7? R9/R8? At the output of OA3/OA4? at the output of OA5?

Comment: The circuit looks OK to me but your power rails are not shown and neither is a waveform of your output and what numbers you expect.

Comment: @MarcusMüller All the outputs I checked. They are fine. Only after the bandpass filter, the gain is 15dB lower than simulated. and centre frequency is shifted.

Comment: There's at least three things in there that act as band pass filter. Which one do you mean? Where exactly did you measure? Against which notion of ground?

Comment: @Andyaka Power rails: biased between 0V and 5V from DC voltage source. Numbers: I added after editing. Output waveform: sinusoidal. The measured picture also I will attach.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I meant the total circuit's output measured between the output node and the 2.5V reference created by voltage divider.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have checked the nodes you asked me to. I am getting signal but after the final active bandpass stage, the signal has lowered gain and centered to 5KHz. Thank you so  much

Answer (score 0):

It's a little counterintuitive, but you need a higher-speed op amp to do low-frequency filtering.  It makes more sense if you think about the fact that attenuation of the higher frequencies must occur from higher amplitude of the negative feedback of this portion of the frequency band.  An LM358 has a gain-bandwidth product of only 1 MHz, so (assuming the circuit is built and biased correctly), this may be your only problem.  It would certainly account for both the lower gain and the increase in center frequency.

Good point by Andy aka as usual though - the swing on this op amp is from zero to V+ - 1.5 (3.5 volts p-p in your case.)  But it's not the best choice in your application in any case.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative circuit to do differential to single ended amplified and band pass signal?  I need to use LM358 only. Thanks for helping me point the problem.

Comment: The gain bandwidth product of an LM358 is 1 MHz.  At your center frequency, of 4 Khz, this means that the open-loop gain (no feedback) of a single op amp is only 250, and you want a gain of about 56.  The only approach I can see to use an LM358 is to use your passive circuit to do all of your filtering, use multiple gain stages with smaller gain, and remove the filtering on the final stage.

Comment: I tried to achieve narrow band with passive circuit once. I could not do so. I also tried to distribute the gain by making the active BPF with 10dB gain and last stage with a simple non inverting amp with variable gain. My output waveform got distorted. Can you suggest how to achieve the specs? Also thank you for clearing this doubt. But I need to know how I should plan the stages? Passive BPF->Difference amp->?

Comment: Also, if you can suggest me a better op amp to make this circuit work on PCB, I will try to procure it. Can you name some ICs please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just look for a "wideband" or "high slew rate" op amp.  Here is one example of a pin-compatible version but there are many  others.  https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/294/NJRC_S_A0008605571_1-2522249.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much